# Filtering custom post using Ajax and taxonomies, keep getting 0

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, taxonomy

Hi everyone I'm having trouble filtering a custom post type "Resources" using Ajax. I'm trying to get the posts to filter via two taxonomies and then activating the Ajax call on a click event on a submit button. I keep getting a '0' response and not sure what I'm missing. If anyone could help me out that would be so much appreciated! Cheers, Sanny

Here's my jQuery:

```
    function filterResources(){
        var the_topic_filter = $('#the_topic_selecter').val();
        var the_resourcetype_filter = $('#the_resourcetype_selecter').val();

        $('#results').html('');
        $('#results').html('<tr><td colspan="5" class="thinking"><img src="/wp-content/themes/limenetwork/images/ajax-spinner.gif" /></td></tr>');

        // AJAX CALL
        var data = {
            action: 'resourcehub_filter',
            send_the_topic_filter : the_topic_filter,
            send_the_resourcetype_filter : the_resourcetype_filter,
        };

        // RESPONSE
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#results').html('');
            $('#results').html(response);

            if(!$.trim(response)){
                $('#results').html('<tr><td colspan="5" class="thinking">We could not find any resources, please try again.</td></tr>');
            }

        });

    }
```

And here is my functions.php

```
// RESOURCE HUB FILTER

add_action( 'wp_ajax_resourcehub_filter', 'resourcehub_filters' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_resourcehub_filter', 'resourcehub_filter' );

function resourcehub_filter() {

    // GET VARS

    $the_topic_filter = $_POST['send_the_topic_filter'];
    $the_resourcetype_filter = $_POST['send_the_resourcetype_filter'];

    // LOOP ALL RESOURCES  (filter)
    global $post;

    // FOR NO FILTERS SELECTED

    if( $the_topic_filter == "" && $the_resourcetype_filter == ""){

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'resource',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );

    } else {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'resource',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',

            'tax_query' => array(

                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'topic_tax',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $the_topic_filter )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'resource_tax',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $the_resourcetype_filter )
                ),

            ),
        );
    }

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($myposts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
            <td>
                <!-- GET ACF TAXONOMY -->
                <?php

                    $terms = get_field('topic');

                    if( $terms ):
                    foreach( $terms as $term ):

                         echo $term->name; echo ' ';

                     endforeach;

                endif; ?>

            </td>
            <td><span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="

                    <?php
                        $terms = get_field('resourcetype');
                        if( $terms ):
                            foreach( $terms as $term ):
                                echo $term->name;
                            endforeach;
                        endif;
                    ?>

            "></span></td>
        </tr>

     <?php endforeach;

    rewind_posts();

    wp_die();

}
```

And I added Ajax like this:

```
// ADD AJAX TO WORDPRESS HEADER
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_ajaxurl' );
function my_ajaxurl() {
    $html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $html .= 'var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '"';
    $html .= '</script>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: The `start_wp();` function has been deprecated since version 1.5. Use `setup_postdata( $post );` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to send html in ajax i do:

```
ob_start();
//here are echo that makes content 
echo '<p>Test</p>'
$response = ob_get_clean();

wp_send_json($response);//die is included
```